# The Definitive Silverlight Book Guide and List

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

So started developing an app with Silverlight. I am learning very quickly it is not like anything I am used to. The problem now because Silverlight is so new and fresh I am kind of lost in terms of books to or guides to read. [www.silverlight.net](http://www.silverlight.net) is nifty but I feel like it is an ad for Silverlight as it is an actual tool. This is a really cool tool I am just a little lost as where to go next.

I guess what I am asking what do you use to learn Silverlight or what do you think I should use to learn Silverlight.

Comment: @Robert What is a good book/ tool to use to learn Silverlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Silverlight 4 Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672333368) is the best I've found by far. It starts by assuming you've got some level of knowledge of Silverlight already (that you can position controls on a page, etc), and if not gives you access to a free version of Silverlight 2 Unleashed online which covers these topics.

From there it gives you a really good feel for Dependency Properties, Binding and ways to structure your application (MVVM), along with tackling some more complex problems you might face.